# Agregar varios botones en jTabbedPane Java

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion y acabo de crear un jTabbedPane pero a cada pestaña de el quiero agregarle mas de un boton o algun punto de seleccion, es decir que en la pestaña1 me quede boton1 y al lado el boton2.

Algo asi como lo que sale en la imagen, eso seria lo ideal

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: algo asi como Los Navegadores? un botton de close tab? o un botton donde? puedes dar un ejemplo de que es lo que quieres hacer. tambien de ser posible proveer codigo de que se ha hecho.

Comment: Lo siento pero no entiendo, ¿podrías agregar alguna especie de diagrama de lo que esoeras obtener?

Comment: La idea es que dentro del jtabbedPane en la pestaña1 aparezca mas de un boton

Comment: ok, ahora entiendo. para hacer lo que deseas necesitas usa un Jpanel y ahi agregar los botones. en cuanto tenga un momento agregare la solucion.

Answer (score -1):

para lograr el effecto que se desea se debe utilizar un `JPanel` el cual contendra los elementos y los organizara(utilizando un Layout) de la forma que deseas. el `Jpanel` se crea de la siguiente forma

```
public class ButtonPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;

public ButtonPanel() {
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT1");
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT2");
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT3");
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT4");
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT5");
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT6");
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT7");
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton("BTT8");
    //este Layout ordena los compentes en el Panel 
    //de forma que se vean como una grilla de 2 filas y 4 collumnas con un espacio
    //vertical y horizontal entre los componentes de 10 
    setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 4, 10, 10));
    add(jButton1);
    add(jButton2);
    add(jButton3);
    add(jButton4);
    add(jButton5);
    add(jButton6);
    add(jButton7);
    add(jButton8);
//...
//agregar eventos a los botones? o otros componentes a el panel
//...
}
//...
}
```

NOTA: esta es solo una forma, otra forma es utilizar un Metodo que cree una instancia de JPanel y agregar el Layout y los bottones:

```
public JPanel getButtonPanel() {
    JButton jButton = new JButton("BTT1");
    //...
    //crear los demas botones
    JPanel tab = new JPanel();
    tab.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(2, 4, 10, 10));
    tab.add(jButton);
    //...
    //agrega el resto de Bottones
    //....
    // agregar eventos etc. 
    return tab;

}
```

esto genera un panel que se vera algo asi:

[image: panel]

para agregarlo al `JTabbedPane` se hace de la siguiente forma:

```
//...
MyTabbedPane= new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
ButtonPanel mytab= new ButtonPanel();
MyTabbedPane.addTab("Pestania 1", mytab);
//...
```

el resultado:

[image: resultado]

lecturas recomendadas:

[tutoriales sobre Panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

[tutorial sobre Layouts](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

OH y otra cosa. para que tenga un borde utilize:

`setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));`
[image: con borde]

Comment: Excelente, entendi y me funciono perfectamente.

Otra cosa las pestañas pueden estar ocultas y al momento de pulsar un boton aparezca dicha pestaña oculta

Comment: depende de "como" quieras "mostrar" o "ocultar" los tabs. por ejemplo una forma simple es Crear un Panel y simplemente no agregarlo al Tabbed pane hasta que le de click al buton. cuando das click `MyTabbedPane.addTab("Pestania 2", mytaboculto);` y de esa forma tienes la referencia, pero no la agregas al tabbed pane hasta hacer click. y para ocultarla simplemente `MyTabbedPane.remove(mytaboculto)` OH! y para cambiar de tab `MyTabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(mytaboculto)`
si respondi tu pregunta no olvides darle upvote y marcar la solucion etc.